# How to add top and bottom margin in addHTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf

how to add margin-bottom and top at multiple pages pdf?

I added plugins jsPDF and html2canvas.

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [400, 455]);
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#exportthis': function(element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};

margins = {
  bottom: 10,
  top: 10,
  left: 10,
  right: 10
};


pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('exportthis'), 10, 10, {
    pagesplit: true
  },
  function(dispose) {
    var pageCount = pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages();
    for (i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
      pdf.setPage(i);
      pdf.text(195, 450, pdf.internal.getCurrentPageInfo().pageNumber + "/" + pageCount + "\n");
    }
    pdf.save("Report.pdf");
  }, margins);
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @ lenilsondc Tx For the editing

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('toHTML'), 10, 10, {pagesplit: true, margin: {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, useFor: 'page'}}, function () {doc.save("Report.pdf")})
```

[Github link](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/pull/1450)

Look at link.It will help

Comment: @ Ravi Patil it does not work, I have already used but its same error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function print javascript:
[Convert HTML,CSS to PDF](https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e)

Comment: Thanks,  for the response but it's not working bcoz it's working on the image. and I have documentation of pdf.